# Login Failed for linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to create a linked server...?

```
1st Server name is ABC.DATABASE1
2nd server name is EFG.DATABASE2
```

EFG database username is `sa` password is `sa`

I want to retrive the data's from 2nd server thourgh 1st server

In the 1st server, i exectue the store procedure like this....

```
exec sp_linkedserver 'EFG'
```

Executed successfully,

When i tried to retrive the data, it is showing error as "`login failed for user sa, Reason: Not associated with trusted sql server connection`"

How to solve this problem...

Need help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio check the login configuration of your linked servers properties on the *Security" tab and create a mapped remote login for your local `sa` account or configure an alternative login for all connections.

To create a linked server with a login mapping by executing `sp_linkedserver`, try

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'EFG', @locallogin = N'sa', @useself = N'False', 
                     @rmtuser = N'your_remote_user', @rmtpassword = N'remotepassword'
```

To create a linked server with an alternative login, try

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'EFG', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', 
                     @rmtuser = N'your_remote_user', @rmtpassword = N'remotepassword'
```