# Connect to a linked database from a net core application

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to connect to a linked server from .net core.
I connect to my SQL Server, but I cannot reach the Oracle Database linked on it.

For example, I can connect to an actual SQL Server Database with the cnnStr:

"Server=foo\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

But if I change the Database parameter to the linked server, I get an error "Cannot open database "dbLINK" requested by the login. The login failed"

Does anyone knows how to connect to a linked database?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This might not be related to net core.  It is more-likely related to linked databases and permissions.  S/O has some answers, but they are hard to find. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732635/login-failed-when-querying-linked-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the right way to do that is either creating views that access your linked server or access your linked server data directly from your query, for example, `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVERNAME], 'SELECT Id, Name, Age from USER');`

It`s important to point out that views are probably gonna be a better practice in this case. If you change anything related to your linked server in the near future, you'll need to change things in only one place.

Comment: You've saved my day. Muito obrigado!